# Introspecting a C++ dll with python and calling function

Tags: python, c++, dll

I'm currently searching a way to call function that are inside a C++ dll. I work with C# and C++ but it seems I can't use reflection on a dll and calling function by their name with a string.

I saw some post on ctypes, but I'm not sure if it would fit my needs. What I need is a python library that could introspect a C++ dll, then I could call function, like for say getFood() with a string like myDll.call('getFood').

Thank you.

Comment: Can you use C++ to call the functions even? As in, are the functions you want to call properly exported in the DLL?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, ctypes is what you need.  use:

```
dllobj = ctypes.WinDLL("dll file name")
```

to load the DLL into memory.  You can then find functions and call them.
[This](http://starship.python.net/crew/theller/ctypes/tutorial.html) does a nice job of explaining.